# Doubts regarding verse 48:10

Tags: quran, tafseer, doubts

In Quran 48:10:

> Indeed, those who pledge allegiance to you, [O Muhammad] - they are actually pledging allegiance to Allah. The hand of Allah is over their hands. So he who breaks his word only breaks it to the detriment of himself. And he who fulfills that which he has promised Allah - He will give him a great reward.

According to the tafsir of ibn kathir, the story follows that the rasool (swl) had heard that Uthman RA was killed. Afterwards, this verse had been revealed as a response to that, however, it became known that Uthman RA was not killed. What exactly was the point of this verse then? Does it not make more sense for Allah to let him know the truth of the matter? I have assimilated my question from thr following article: https://atheism-vs-islam.com/index.php/divine-revelation-or-human-drama/52-revelation-exposed-allah-didn-t-know-that-uthman-was-not-killed-in-the-incident-of-bait-e-ridhwan-hudaybiyyah. It sets the same type of format alongside supposed apologetic rebuttals. I'd appreciate if someone could dismantle this disgusting falsehood being made of our rasool (swl).